# capitalizedString capitalizes words after hyphens?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a curious case dealing with the `capitalizedString` method for `NSString`.

I called `capitalizedString` on the following string "bloor-yonge"

and it returned: `"Bloor-Yonge"`

I recalled specifically reading from the dev documentation the following with regards to `capitalizedString`:

"Other common word delimiters such as hyphens and other punctuation are not considered, so this method may not generally produce the desired results for multiword strings."

I am curious as to know why `yonge-->` becomes `Yonge` and why this happened despite the stated exception in the documentation. Can anyone elucidate for this?

Thank you for your time and response in advance!

P.S It actually did what I wanted it to do -- I'm simply curious for future's sake when I may not want the post-hyphen word capitalized.

Comment: The documentation is either out of date or just wrong, or there is a bug in the `capitalizedString` method. There is a link at the bottom of the reference document that allows you to report such an issue. Let Apple know of the discrepancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Method will work for you, Check the output of this method

```
- (NSString *)CapitalizeString:(NSString *)str {


    [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"#Check# "];

    [str capitalizedString];

    [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#Check# " withString:@"-"];

    return str;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Junaid, capitalizedString actually does that, if I'm not mistaken. I was wondering if that was a bug in Apple's Code something else. Thank you for the code though, good to know ways around the potential issue.

Comment: capitalizedString doesn't that feature, if this method work for you then mark this answer as correct